# How do you mock queries that has comparison logic for testing in DJANGO

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, orm, mocking

Let's say I have two class:

```
class Classroom(models.Model):
   num_of_students= models.IntegerField

class School(models.Model):
   classroom = models.ForeignKey(Classroom, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I am trying to write a Mock that would return records for this query:

```
School.objects.filter(classroom__num_of_students__lt=40)
```

In test so far I have

```
school = School()
classroom = Classroom(num_of_students=10)
mock.patch.object(school, 'classrooms', MockSet(classroom))
mock.patch.object(School, 'objects', MockSet(school))
```

I don't want to mock 'filter'. I would like filter to keep its behavior.

Comment: do you really need to mock it? maybe creating fixtures and load them would be better approach https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.TransactionTestCase.fixtures

Comment: I don't want to use the database.

Comment: If you [set it up](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#s-std:setting-TEST_NAME), Django will use an in-memory database for tests.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but i'm really just looking to stub.